# Getter and Setter Functions in Solidity not showing any output

Tags: solidity, remix

I have written a smart contract with the Getter and Setter functions but it is not showing any output in IDE-Remix. My code is
'''

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract GetandSet{

    string name;
    uint age;

    function GetandSet() public {



    }

    function set(string newName, uint newAge) public {

        name = newName;
        age = newAge;
    } 


    function get() public view returns (string, uint) {

        return (name,age);
    }


}
```

'''

Comment: How are you testing it? It works just fine here. Just choose the right compilier version, deploy it to JavaScript VM, issue a `set` with some values and issue a `get`

Comment: I am compiling it through Remix -IDE (browser-based) and using the compiler version 0.4.21.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. I guess you have problems using Remix.

So:

1) Choose the right compiler (0.4.21)

2) Deploy the contract

3) Call `set` with some values

4) Call `get` and you should see the set values

Attached is a screenshot of the setup I tested with. As you can see, the `get` function gives the correct results.

[image: Instructions]

Answer (score 0):

set string with memory location. like i mentioned in code with "memory" keyword.

function set(string memory newName, uint newAge) public {

```
    name = newName;
    age = newAge;
} 


function get() public view returns (string memory, uint) {

    return (name,age);
}
```